# Rails active_support uninitialized constant I18n (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, activesupport

I'm running Rails 5.2.3 with Ruby 2.6.5.

For no apparent reason, all of a sudden I'm getting errors related to I18n with active_support. I have no desire to do internationalization and would be quite content without any trace of it. I understand this is built-in to a degree, but can't understand why all of a sudden the following error. The latest operation I did was to modify my application configuration to enable sql schema file. I backed out that change to no avail. I cannot migrate now or even run the server.

```
    16: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    15: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    14: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:3:in `require'
    12: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:3:in `require'
    10: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support.rb:27:in `require'
     8: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:3:in `require'
     6: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `require'
     4: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     3: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:3:in `require'
     2: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:6:in `require'
/home/lloydo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/i18n.rb:15:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant I18n (NameError)
```

When I run bundle, it tells me that i18n is being used:

```
Using rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
Using i18n 1.8.11
Using minitest 5.14.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.9
```

Viewing the offending file, I expect it's the last line causing the issue:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge"
require "active_support/core_ext/hash/except"
require "active_support/core_ext/hash/slice"
begin
  require "i18n"
rescue LoadError => e
  $stderr.puts "The i18n gem is not available. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install"
  raise e
end
require "active_support/lazy_load_hooks"

ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:i18n)
I18n.load_path << File.expand_path("locale/en.yml", __dir__)
```

I do have the en.yml file located in the locale folder.

*I also updated my bundler version from 2.2.29 to 2.2.31 - in case that's a factor?*

application.rb as below:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Gybm
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.0

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.

    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
  end
end
```

Comment: Hello @dbugger, thankyou, thankyou, thankyou...you led me to the answer. Thinking of the gem file, I got to thinking of the ruby version it was using...it didn't quite add up. Somewhere along the line I ended up with ruby 2.6.5 configured...I cannot see why or when. It should have been on 2.5.7. Putting this back got me up and running again. I'm in the process of re-writing in RoR 6+ at the moment, so this will remain only until I am complete.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby version was inadvertently updated far beyond original version used. This was not intentional, thus causing the issue. Putting ruby version back to original resolved the issue.

Comment: You could add more detail to this answer, for example infos from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70069912/rails-active-support-uninitialized-constant-i18n-nameerror#comment123878164_70069912)?